# symfony 4: problem with twig stylesheets and path

Tags: twig, symfony4

i worke with Symfony 4. Run the browser after installation and a nice welcome greeting shows. All good!

Then I created a new controller using make:controller. I named this controller Soumission and is using Annotations, same with the other Default Controller. I configured the routing as follows:

```
class SoummissionController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/soumission/liste", name="liste_soumission")
     */
    public function soumission()
    {
        return $this->render('soummission/liste_soumission.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'SoummissionController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And i created my view that extend **base.html.twig** as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello SoummissionController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, magni incidunt voluptatem voluptas quos sint temporibus corrupti odit quae neque quis delectus saepe optio provident dolorum veritatis aliquid! Quod, iste!</p>
<p>Eveniet recusandae repudiandae id reprehenderit! Ex ab corrupti architecto quasi soluta totam, quae, commodi, vero accusantium repellendus placeat voluptate tenetur blanditiis a voluptatum nihil amet at expedita reiciendis distinctio odit.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

My page **base.html.twig** contains css and javascript as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/iconfonts/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />

        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>

    <div class="container-scroller">
      {# partial:partials/_navbar.html #}
      <nav class="navbar default-layout-navbar col-lg-12 col-12 p-0 fixed-top d-flex flex-row">
          <div class="text-center navbar-brand-wrapper d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <img src="images/logo.jpg" a.....
```

now when I try to access my page via the path: **http://localhost:8000/soumission/liste** the symfony server can not load the css and the javascripte of the **base.html.twig** page and the server trace level show me its errors as follows:

```
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:38 2019] 127.0.0.1:61350 [404]: /soumission/vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:42 2019] 127.0.0.1:61357 [404]: /soumission/css/footer.css
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:45 2019] 127.0.0.1:61358 [404]: /soumission/images/logo.jpg
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:48 2019] 127.0.0.1:61360 [404]: /soumission/images/acceuil.jpg
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:51 2019] 127.0.0.1:61365 [404]: /soumission/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:53 2019] 127.0.0.1:61371 [404]: /soumission/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.addons.js
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:55 2019] 127.0.0.1:61376 [404]: /soumission/js/off-canvas.js
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:57 2019] 127.0.0.1:61382 [404]: /soumission/js/misc.js
[Tue Mar 19 11:53:59 2019] 127.0.0.1:61387 [404]: /soumission/js/dashboard.js
[Tue Mar 19 11:54:01 2019] 127.0.0.1:61390 [404]: /soumission/images/dao.png
[Tue Mar 19 11:54:02 2019] 127.0.0.1:61394 [404]: /soumission/images/soumission.png
[Tue Mar 19 11:54:04 2019] 127.0.0.1:61398 [404]: /soumission/images/comission.png
[Tue Mar 19 11:54:06 2019] 127.0.0.1:61402 [404]: /soumission/images/traitement.png
[Tue Mar 19 11:54:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:61406 [404]: /soumission/images/approbation.png
[Tue Mar 19 11:54:12 2019] 127.0.0.1:61408 [404]: /soumission/images/pv.jpg
[Tue Mar 19 11:54:14 2019] 127.0.0.1:61421 [404]: /soumission/images/favicon.png
[Tue Mar 19 12:19:25 2019] 127.0.0.1:62631 [404]: /soumission/liste
```

please, i need help

Comment: Do those files actually exist on your server?

Comment: I am curious to know what your ```.htaccess``` file looks like and if it would help to remove the ```.html.``` from the ```.twig``` extension.

Answer (score 0):

It's path  problem

Try  this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendors/iconfonts/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendors/css/vendor.bundle.base.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/footer.css') }}">
```

Comment: would be nice if you can submit my anwser as correct